# Which algorithm is capable of solving a combinatorial optimization problem like this?

Tags: optimization, combinatorics

The problem I have at hand is a regression problem where each of $p$ inputs, $x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_p$, needs to undergo a variable transformation using one of $q$ basis functions from a set of available functions $F = \{ f_1, f_2, f_3, \cdots, f_q \}$. The cost function is the Mean Square Error (MSE) defined as $MSE = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n (y_k - \hat{y}_k)^2$, where $n$ is the number of samples and for each $k$, $y_k$ is an experimental value and $\hat{y}_k$ is the predicted value computed by some method (e.g., as from a Gaussian Process Regression) using the transformations ($f_j(x_i)$) as input variables. This method must be also selected from a set $M = \{ M_1, M_2, M_3, \cdots, M_m \}$ of widely different available methods. The objective is to decide which function transforms each one of the $p$ inputs and which method to use such that $MSE$ is minimum. There are no constraints whatsoever.

Any advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can each $x_i$ get transformed by a different $f_j$, or do you need to pick a single $f_j$ that works well for all $x_i$?

Comment: Either each $x_i$ can be transformed by a different basis function $f_j$, or the same $f_j$ can transform different $x_i$. For example, either assignment $\{ f_1(x_2), f_2(x_3), f_3(x_1) \}$ or $\{ f_1(x_2), f_2(x_3), f_2(x_1) \}$ is allowed

Comment: how big are $p$, $q$, and $n$?   Can you constraint the functions $f$ in any way (e.g. are they smooth, or Lipschitz continuous, convex, etc.)?

Comment: $p \leq 20$ and $n \leq 500$. The basis functions are very simple functions like $F = \{ x, x^2, x^3, x^4, |x|, e^x, e^{-x^2}, \sin x, \cos x, \sinh x, \cosh x \}$, up to $q = 30$. The regression multivariate methods/models can be Gaussian Process Regression, Support Vector Machine, Radial Basis Functions, Polynomials up to 4th degree, Linear Function, Splines, etc..

Comment: Check out https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing